# Android Espresso how to write cases for Fragments and its child's from Activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-espresso

I am working on writing the test cases for my application and it worked well for Activities. But when it comes to Fragment inside the ViewPager my cases are failed.

Below test case fails because the fragment shows an empty view if run this directly.

```
public class SentimentsFragmentEspressoTest {

    @Rule
    public FragmentTestRule<SentimentsFragment> mFragmentTestRule = new FragmentTestRule<>(SentimentsFragment.class);

    @Test
    public void fragment_can_be_instantiated() {

        // Launch the activity to make the fragment visible
        mFragmentTestRule.launchActivity(null);

        // Then use Espresso to test the Fragment

        onView(withId(R.id.listSentiments))
                .perform(RecyclerViewActions.scrollToPosition(4));
    }
}
```

How do I overcome this issue?

Comment: Possibly because you are calling `launchActivity(null);` so the view will be empty/null.

Comment: @H.Brooks, launchActivity() has the Intent parameter. How to send fragment?

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solutions for my above question. Here is the code snippet.

```
 ViewInteraction recyclerView = onView(
                       allOf(withId(R.id.listSentiments),
                               withParent(withId(R.id.viewpager)),
                               isDisplayed()));
               recyclerView.perform(actionOnItemAtPosition(3, click()));
```

From this way you can access all the fragments which is connected with Viewpager.

Answer (score 0):

For Fragment inside the ViewPager try to use in your Test

```
@Rule
public ActivityTestRule<YourActivity> mActivityRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(YourActivity.class);

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {

    //get fragment
    mActivityRule.getActivity()
            .getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();


}

@Test
public void testRecyclerView() {

    //click on item recyclerview
    onView(withId(R.id.listSentiments)).perform(RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItemAtPosition(0, click()));
    ....
    ...
```

Comment: No Luck. it gives below exceptions **java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager com.MyActivity.getSupportFragmentManager()'** on a null object reference